# Get my facebook friends visited places in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I've implemented login using Facebook account in iOS app developing using `Swift`. Now want to get list of all places visited by my facebook friends.

Referred this document but could not found search visited places API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search/

Is it possible?

Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing data of friends (or any user) is not possible, unless they specifically authorized your App with the neccessary permissions.

Comment: yes I know but want to know is it possible to get list of places?

Comment: your question is "list of all places visited by my facebook friends", i only answered to that. there is no general list of places though.